# How to use a SOAP API in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, soap

I've trying to use the API for CapsuleCRM...

http://capsulecrm.com/help/page/api_gettingstarted

I've been reading some articles on SOAP in asp.net and I just don't get it. Most of them seem to be ablut creating a web service, not using it and none of them seem to explain how to use basic HTTP authentication.

I have got as far as constructing the XML i want to send to the API but I could really do with seeing some example code which makes an http call using http authentication to a SOAP API.

Maybe I'm just searching for the wrong thing but I've drawn a blank so far. Can anybody show me how?

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the interface in question is **REST** - not SOAP.....

Check out the [WCF REST Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF/REST) for a great intro on how to do REST based calls to REST based API's like this one. Lots of articles, lots of screencasts showing how to do things, from consuming the simplest service to more advanced topics.

Highly recommended!

See a comparison of [REST vs SOAP](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/431.cfm) for a few insights.

Comment: Gah! I am an idiot. One of the other APIs that I was looking at was SOAP and I've got myself confused. Thanks.

Comment: Actually that interface is not REST it is Http-based Type I.  See this link http://nordsc.com/ext/classification_of_http_based_apis.html#http-type-one for differences